# Transfer the data from S3 to FTP server via stream using Python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, ftp, ftplib, python-s3fs

Using Python, I want to copy files that match a pattern `sample1` from AWS S3 to FTP server directly without any downloads to local temporary location.
I attempted the following:

```
import s3fs
from ftplib import FTP_TLS

s3 = s3fs.S3FileSystem(anon=False)
pattern = 'sample1'
rest = [i for i in list if pattern in i]
rest

ftp = FTP_TLS("ftp.test.com")
ftp.login(user ='myUser', passwd = 'PassWrd')
ftp.cwd("box_dest")

for f in rest:
    print(f)
    with open(f, 'r') as fu:
        ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + f, fu)
```

I'm getting:

```
[u'test-bucket/abc/test/sample1.csv']
test-bucket/abc/test/sample1.csv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'test-bucket/abc/test/sample1.csv'
```

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read the file from S3, you need to use `S3FileSystem.open`, not `os.open`.

And you need to extract just a filename from the original S3 path, when specifying the target FTP path. [`posixpath.basename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) should do.

```
for f in rest:
    print(f)
    with s3.open(f, 'r') as fu:
        ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + posixpath.basename(f), fu)
```

Comment: It Works Thanks @Martin Prikryl